# There was a problem during the Python upgrade in MacOs

Tags: python, python-3.x

There was a problem during the Python upgrade in MacOs.

Currently my Python version is 3.7.5, and I want to upgrade to 3.8.1.
So I ran the below command

> $ brew switch python 3.8.1.
>   $ brew link --overwrite python

The problem started with the first command.
errors blow

> $ brew switch python 3.8.1.
>   Error: python does not have a version
>   "3.8.1" in the Cellar.
>   python's installed versions: 3.7.6_1

So I just tried to delete python 3.7.5

> iseungmin  ~
>    sudo rm -rf /Applications/Python\ 3.7
>   Password:
>    iseungmin  ~
>    python -V
>   Python 3.7.5

but still python version is 3.7.5
what should i do?
i want to build python 3.8.1
please, let me know guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to first install Python 3.8.x. Then you can switch:

```
brew install python@3.8    # Installs the latest version of Python 3.8.x
brew switch python 3.8.6   # Activate version just installed
```

You may need to adjust version "3.8.6" in the latter command.